# Angular 2 site page refresh works on localhost but shows 404 error on refresh on live server

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have made a website using Angular 2. I have deployed the site on a linux server in production. The routes seem to work fine when I click the links on the navigation but it shows 404 error when the page is refreshed. Everything seems to work fine on localhost but not on the live server. I even tried using **HashLocationStrategy** but to no avail.

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { RulesComponent } from './rules/rules.component';
import { DownloadsComponent } from './downloads/downloads.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'rules', component: RulesComponent},
    {path: 'downloads', component: DownloadsComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { RulesComponent } from './rules/rules.component';
import { DownloadsComponent } from './downloads/downloads.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    RulesComponent,
    DownloadsComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [ {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My base href is "/". Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the server to redirect all requests except files (and API's for instance) to index.html at the root, so that Angular Router can process the routes.

I assume that's done on your development server, so you need to configure your production server with the same settings. It's not related with `base href` or `location strategy` (assuming that you've got them working with your development server), it's all about the `rewrite rules` for the production server should have.

If you're using Apache, try this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/yourproject>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yourproject
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /yourproject/index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

**Edit:** I assumed that you serve the app on a root-level domain (ex: www.yoursite.com, yourapp.somedomain.com). If the app root URL is like `www.somedomain.com/some-app`, then you'll need to set appropriate `base href` bindings.